# How does quotes inside template expression work in angular1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with an existing codebase and I need to figure out how this works:

```
{{'some_variable' | translate}}
```

It seems to correlate to `some_variable` in an api call but I don't see it in the controller.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz how does 'some_variable' get injected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this project you are using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/01_conceptual-overview)...

This module offers you directive, filter and a service to add translation into your application...

In the example you gave you are using **translate filter** (if you are not familiar with the angular filters check out [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))...

There are some options that how angular translate get your translations but at the end it will something like javascript object like this...

```
{
  some_variable: 'Some Variable translation'  
}
```

translate filter will take your input 'some_variable' and find value for it from given translations (if it cannot find anything it will return key itself)...